# Printing a randomly removed element from an array list, then printing out the updated array list

Tags: java, random, arraylist

So I'm having problem printing out a randomly chosen element from an arraylist and then printing the updated arraylist without that random element in it. Every time I print the updated list, it gives me the arraylist minus the randomly chosen element and minus another element.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class LabPartyGuests   {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int numberOfGuests = 4;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random();
      ArrayList<String> guestList = new ArrayList<String>();

      System.out.println("Please enter 4 guests: ");
      System.out.print("guest1: ");
      String guest1 = input.nextLine();
      System.out.print("guest2: ");
      String guest2 = input.nextLine();
      System.out.print("guest3: ");
      String guest3 = input.nextLine();
      System.out.print("guest4: ");
      String guest4 = input.nextLine();

      for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)   {
         guestList.add(guest1);
         guestList.add(guest2);
         guestList.add(guest3);
         guestList.add(guest4);
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Guest list: " + guestList);
      System.out.println();

      guestList.remove(rand.nextInt(4));
      System.out.printf("%s can't come %n", guestList.remove(rand.nextInt(4)));
      for (int i = 0; i < guestList.size(); i++)   {
         guestList.size();
      }  
      System.out.print(guestList);
   }
}
```

Comment: How many times do you call remove() on the list? Once, or twice? Then why are you surprised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing two elements :

```
  guestList.remove(rand.nextInt(4)); // one
  System.out.printf("%s can't come %n", guestList.remove(rand.nextInt(4))); // two
```

If you want to print the removed element, store the output of the first remove instead of calling remove twice :

```
  String removed = guestList.remove(rand.nextInt(4));
  System.out.println("removed element " + removed);
```

Comment: How do I get it to print the removed element? If I just put rand.nextInt(4) there it just prints out the index.

Comment: @james13 `remove(int index)` returns the removed element. Just write `String removed = guestList.remove(rand.nextInt(4));`

Comment: Thanks I figured it out without using that, but thanks for the tip! :)